# sympy modulo doesn't work with non-commutative expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code:

```
y = IndexedBase('y')
z = y[0] % 2000
```

This gives the error:

```
sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: non-commutative expressions are not supported
```

I believe this is because of the IndexedBase term. What is an alternate way to represent `z = y[0] % 2000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

in the latest version of sympy 0.7.6 (was using a slightly older version previously), indexedBase objects are made to be commutative by default. So just download the newer version of sympy and i can use the Mod operator.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/7355